# Cocoa Preferences Overwritten

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a couple questions regarding application preferences using NSUserDefaults.

In my last app I would link my preferences using bindings to NSUserDefaults, and this worked perfectly. In the application startup methods I could then perform actions based on the values stored in the NSUserDefaults.

The problem occured when I updated my application and re-distributed it, in which all the settings would get over-written with the preferences in my computer. So if someone changed the settings, and then received the update, their settings would get over-written with mine.

Looking back at the Apple documentation in regards to saving Preferences, I notice the following line which I didn't use, which is used to write preferences to disk:

```
[defaults synchronize];
```

My question is, does this code write the preferences to the user's harddrive, so that if I re-distribute the application with different settings, NSUserDefaults will read from the disk instead?

Sorry for the misunderstanding but I can't find an answer.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: I think `synchronize` is a red herring — it should happen behind the scenes anyway. How are you setting your initial values for those preferences?

Comment: NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

Comment: The preferences are then set using bindings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use bindings to control your preferences, you should be using `NSUserDefaultsController`. In either case, to set initial values for your defaults, you should create a dictionary with the initial values and then pass it to `registerDefaults:` if you're using vanilla NSUserDefaults, or one of `initWithDefaults:initialValues:` or `setInitialValues:` if you're using NSUserDefaultsController. Here's an NSUserDefaultsExample:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching {
    // For decent-sized applications, I normally like to store this in its own plist
    // but I'm creating it in-line here for readability's sake.
    NSDictionary *initialPreferences = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSNumber numberWithInteger:21], @"UserAge",
        @"red", @"FavoriteColor",
        @"Idaho", "Location", nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:initialPreferences];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but am i safe in saying if I include a 'synchronize' call on applicationTerminate then the user preferences will be saved and not be overwritten when the application is updated?

Comment: @Cristian: I'm not sure you're safe in saying that, because that should happen automatically when the application terminates. If it's not happening, there's something not working right.

Comment: no no, the preferences do synchronize automatically, but if i then overwrite that app with another version, than the preferences get overwritten by the new app's preferences. Or have i got it all wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Cristian: As long as the new app has the same bundle identifier, the preferences shouldn't get overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` are only written when **`synchronize`** is called.

When you ship your app and you want specific settings in place at first launch, you need to set these yourself in code. I usually look for a `nil` value for a specific key and if it an empty value, I will set the desired "default" value.

### Example

I do this when the application launches:

```
NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

/*  count how many times the user has launched the app  */
int total = [[defaults objectForKey:@"kLaunchCount"] intValue];  total++;
[defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:total] forKey:@"kLaunchCount"];

/*  User chose to reset Scanner Feed, remove the .plist from Documents directory.  */
if ( [[defaults objectForKey:@"kResetScannerFeeds"] boolValue] == YES ){
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:SCANNERFEED error:nil];
    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"kResetScannerFeeds"];
}

/*  Check to see if Default Prefs are NULL, if so, enable them.  */
if ( [defaults objectForKey:@"kShakeToToggleVisibility"] == nil ){
    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"kShakeToToggleVisibility"];
}
if ( [defaults objectForKey:@"kBackgroundAudio"] == nil ){
    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"kBackgroundAudio"];
}
if ( [defaults objectForKey:@"kUseMyLocation"] == nil ){
    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"kUseMyLocation"];
}
if ( [defaults objectForKey:@"kAttachTwitterIcon"] == nil ){
    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"kAttachTwitterIcon"];
}
if ( [defaults objectForKey:@"kAttachTwitterLink"] == nil ){
    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"kAttachTwitterLink"];
}
/*  User chose to log out of Facebook Session, do that now.  */
if ( [[defaults objectForKey:@"kLogoutFacebook"] boolValue] == YES ){
    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"kLogoutFacebook"];
    [self fbLogout];
}

[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: Perfect. When i check the defaults of my app and there are several defaults set, if i still ship the application, if the user has had preferences written to disk, those preferences will overwrite mine? Thanks for your answer

Comment: This isn't the best way to do it — NSUserDefaults provides `registerDefaults:` for precisely this purpose.

Comment: @Chuck could you possibly provide an example or a link so I can see how to do it correctly? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, there is always `registerDefaults`, but I like to have more control over my code — and it's one less .plist I have to include in my project.

Comment: I agree with Chuck: providing default preferences in a plist and loading that via `registerDefaults:` is a lot easier.

Comment: I'll take a look at register defaults, thanks. But am i safe in saying if I include a 'synchronize' call on applicationTerminate then the user preferences will be saved and not be overwritten?

Comment: `synchronize` is only needed in rare cases! `NSUserDefaults` gets automatically saved to disc behind the scenes, there is little need to call `synchronize` manually except when you want to make sure that the defaults gets written to disk right away.

Comment: @JustSid Thanks for the clarification, makes more sense now :)